# MVC 4 SimpleMembership - Doing it right the first time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Folks,

I just started to design a new web project. From VS2012, I generated a new Internet website project. It comes with a database that is already laid out with a few tables. This is fine.

Now, I need to extend the database with a few new tables and update UserProfile with few new fields. However, as this is going to be a new database, I don't want to enable migration steps and add code-bloat that is not really needed.

Here is the workaround I found:

1. Extend UserProfile with new fields as you would want to.
2. Add new tables in AccountModels.cs. For example,

   [Table("Items")]
    public class Items {
       ...
    }
3. For each new table, add a DbSet field to UsersContexts class in AccountModels.cs.

   public class UserContext : DbContext {

   ```
    ...
    public DbSet<Items> Items {get; set; }
   ```

   }
4. Delete the original database file, create a new database file with the same name, and run the application.

Voila. The new database gets filled with all the tables.

Is this the right way to do it?

Although it works, I am not really sure about step 3. I figured somehow the framework needs to know that a new table needs to be created and essentially adding a new field to UserContext triggers the creation of the new table. Is this the approach right?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: The technology you are using is Entity framework code first. You can start [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx) and follow the links to latest information to know how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By not using code first migrations, deleting the database manually is the best thing you can do. There is also the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges initializer but be careful to never use it in a release version of your app.

I would also recommend to write the DbContext in a seperate cs file. When you use the fluent api to configure the EF relations (what i would do), it can get really big. Think about putting the DAL and your models in seperate projects when your solution gets bigger. Using multiple contexts for one db can also cause problems, so naming it SomeAppContext would be better.